# Python: Change file names to the names of people in a list

Tags: python, powerpoint

I have a couple slides, each slide corresponds to a person. I need to name each file (.pptx) after the individual name it references. A lot of the examples I see on mass renaming have the renaming become sequential like:

```
file1
file2
file3
```

I need:

```
bob.pptx
sue.pptx
jack.pptx
```

I was able to change names using os found on this site https://www.marsja.se/rename-files-in-python-a-guide-with-examples-using-os-rename/:

```
import os, fnmatch
file_path = 'C:\\Users\\Documents\\Files_To_Rename\\Many_Files\\'
files_to_rename = fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(file_path), '*.pptx')
print(files_to_rename)
new_name = 'Datafile'

for i, file_name in enumerate(files_to_rename):
    new_file_name = new_name + str(i) + '.pptx'
    
    os.rename(file_path + file_name, 
          file_path + new_file_name)
```

But again, this just names it:

```
Datafile1
Datafile2
etc
```

Comment: Well, yes, because that's what your code does. Where should the names come from?

Comment: From where do we get the names which corresponds to the slides?

Comment: I have a list of names in a txt, but am unsure how to reference it in this code

Comment: Presumably, the slide contains the person's name. Use python-pptx to read the name from the pptx file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your suggestions, I think I found it with a friend's help:

```
import os, fnmatch
import pandas as pd
file_path = 'C:\\Users\\Documents\\FolderwithFiles\\'
files_to_rename = fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(file_path), '*.pptx') #looks for any .ppt in path, can make any ext

df = pd.read_excel('Names.xlsx') #make a list of names in an xl, this won't read the header, header should be Names, then list your names)

for i, file_name in zip(df['Names'], files_to_rename): #zip instead of a nest for loop
    new_file_name = i + '.pptx'
    os.rename(file_path + file_name, file_path + new_file_name)
    print(new_file_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

my example

```py
import os from pathlib
import Path
files = os.listdir("c:\\tmp\\")
for key in range(0, len(files)):
  print (files[key])
  os.rename("c:\\tmp\\" + files[key], "c:\\tmp\\" + files[key].replace("-",""))
  Path("c:\\tmp\\" + files[key] + '.ok').touch() # if u need add some extension
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I ran your code (avoiding file paths I don't have!), getting it to print output not just rename

```
import os, fnmatch
file_path = '.\\'
files_to_rename = fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(file_path), '*.pptx')
print(files_to_rename)
new_name = 'Datafile'

for i, file_name in enumerate(files_to_rename):
    new_file_name = new_name + str(i) + '.pptx'

    print (file_path + new_file_name)

    os.rename(file_path + file_name, 
              file_path + new_file_name)
```

This gave me

```
.\Datafile0.pptx
.\Datafile1.pptx
...
```

and did give me the correct sequence of pptx files in that folder.

So I suspect the problem is that you *are* getting the file names you want, but you can't see them in Windows. Solution: show file types in Windows. Here's one of many available links as to how: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/show-file-extensions-in-windows

Comment: Hey! I need it to pull from a list of names I have. The example I shared is the only thing I could find and it was just a sequential list of a name I had to give. I don't know how to pull from the list I have (just a names.txt list) so the output is then jack.pptx, sue.pptx, bob.pptx

Comment: Try: `for file_name in enumerate(files_to_rename):
    new_file_name = myDesiredNameList[i] + '.pptx' ...`

IF this isn't what you meant, can you post your attempt showing what you do mean, working or not, and we may be able to show how to get it working.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it with the answer I posted!